# Difference between class of a | b vs class of a | class of b

Tags: typescript

Is there a difference between defining:

```
Class<A | B>
```

and:

```
Class<A> | Class<B>
```

where `Class` is:

```
export type Class<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

Comment: The `Class` you've added is quite a specific thing, but in a deleted comment you said you meant just "any generic." I'm not sure what you mean by that...? E.g., the answers differ if you specifically mean your `Class` above vs. (say) `Map`, `Set`, `Array`, or many other generic types. You can't generalize from an answer for what you have above and generics in general. (Not least because a *constructor* function such as `Class` can't literally return a union. I *think* -- but could be wrong -- there's no functional difference with your `Class`, but there very much is with other generic types.)

Comment: These are essentially the same thing for the particular definition of `Class<T>` you've written (although a [mre] would need definitions for `A` and `B` also).  In general `F<X | Y>` and `F<X> | F<Y>` are not the same, though.  Does that address the question (in which case @T.J.Crowder might want to answer) or is there something I'm missing about it?